# associate contact with account using salesforce api

Tags: php, api, salesforce

I am new to using the salesforce api. I have downloaded the saleforce/php toolkit and am able to successfully create contacts and accounts from a webform on my server.

To create a contact I am doing the following:

```
    $records[0] = new stdclass();
    $records[0]->FirstName = $FirstName;
    $records[0]->LastName = $LastName;
    $records[0]->Email = $Email;
    $records[0]->Phone = $Phone;
    $records[0]->MailingStreet = $MailingStreet;
    $records[0]->MailingCity = $MailingCity;
    $records[0]->MailingState = $MailingState;
    $records[0]->MailingPostalCode = $MailingPostalCode;
    $records[0]->MailingCountry = $MailingCountry;
    $records[0]->LeadSource = $LeadSource;

    $create = $mySforceConnection->create($records, 'Contact');
```

To create an account I am doing the following

```
    $records[0] = new stdclass();
    $records[0]->Name = $Name

    $create = $mySforceConnection->create($records, 'Account');
```

Can anyone give me a simple example of how I would associate a contact with an account?

I have a check-box on the form that asks if this is an organization. If the user checks this box I would like to create an organization account with some of the data and create a contact with some of the data and associate the two.

I am not looking for a full blown working example but more just somthing pointing me in the right direction.

Lets say I have an account with the id of 001Z0000004XeWfIAK

I have tried

```
    $records[0] = new stdclass();
    $records[0]->FirstName = $FirstName;
    $records[0]->LastName = $LastName;
    $records[0]->Email = $Email;
    $records[0]->Phone = $Phone;
    $records[0]->MailingStreet = $MailingStreet;
    $records[0]->MailingCity = $MailingCity;
    $records[0]->MailingState = $MailingState;
    $records[0]->MailingPostalCode = $MailingPostalCode;
    $records[0]->MailingCountry = $MailingCountry;
    $records[0]->LeadSource = $LeadSource;
    $records[0]->AccountId = '001Z0000004XeWfIAK';

    $create = $mySforceConnection->create($records, 'Contact');
```

@ superfell

it returns this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [errors] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [message] =>  A Household Contact's account must be a household.
                            [statusCode] => FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION
                        )

                )

            [id] => 
            [success] => 
        )

)
```

But I am trying to associate a contact with an orginization

Comment: Does the contact get created at all? Do you get any errors?

Comment: You need to example $create to see why the create failed.

Comment: I am sorry. I don't think I am being clear. I have an account type called organization. Every organization has contacts associated with them. I am trying to associate contacts with the organization

Comment: When you create the account, you need to set the recordTypeId to a record type that's not the household recordtype.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I am answering this myself because I cant mark Superfell comment as the answer. But his comment

**"When you create the account, you need to set the recordTypeId to a record type that's not the household recordtype. – superfell"**

helped me get the answer.

Here is my final code to create a account and then a contact of that account.

```
    //First I create a simple account
    //With no recordTypeId specified it defaults to the the type I want

    $records[0] = new stdclass();
    $records[0]->Name = $Name;

    //Create a new orginization account
    $org = $mySforceConnection->create($records, 'Account');
```

After creating the Account, Salesforce returns a success message with the new AccountId

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 001Z0000004XfXcIAK
            [success] => 1
        )

)
```

Then I am able to create a contact and associate it with my new account

```
    $contact[0] = new stdclass();
    $contact[0]->FirstName = $FirstName;
    $contact[0]->LastName = $LastName;
    $contact[0]->Email = $Email;
    $contact[0]->Phone = $Phone;
    $contact[0]->MailingStreet = $MailingStreet;
    $contact[0]->MailingCity = $MailingCity;
    $contact[0]->MailingState = $MailingState;
    $contact[0]->MailingPostalCode = $MailingPostalCode;
    $contact[0]->MailingCountry = $MailingCountry;
    $contact[0]->LeadSource = $LeadSource;

    //This is where my problem was, Thanks again superfell
    //$organization_contact = My custom Salesforce contact type ID, E.G. recordTypeId
    $contact[0]->recordTypeId = $orginization_contact;

    //The AccountId is the account I want to associate this contact with.
    //AccountId was returned by Salesforce upon the creation of the account (See above)  
    $contact[0]->AccountId = $org[0]->id;

    $contact = $mySforceConnection->create($contact, 'Contact');
```

**Thank you again to Jeremey and Superfell. Saved me hours.**

Answer (score 6):

Contact has an `AccountId` field. So the code below assumes you have the account id in a variable called `$accountId` and `$resource[0]` is the contact you want to associate.

```
$records[0]->AccountId = $accountId
$mySforceConnection->update($records)
```

I don't know php very well, but I think this would be close to correct.

Comment: Thanks Jeremmy. I believe I have tried this. I updated my question above

Comment: There is no other association except through AccountId, but the account must first be created first so that you could get its Id to use in Contact.AccountId. What you get is a custom validation error requiring a match of record types for Account/Contact, check the validation rule and assign appropriate record types